# Cálculo de area con opencv

Tags: python, imagen, opencv

Estoy intentando realizar un codigo para el calculo de area de un objeto por medio de una foto, hasta los momentos he logrado que el sistema me identifique correctamente los bordes y me tome el area, sin embargo, tengo algunos errores ya que toma algunos valores dentro del objeto en vez de descartarlo, por ejemplo: si la caja tiene etiqueta toma no solo el rectangulo que deseo, si no que toma tambien el contorno interno, así que la primera pregunta es: como evito que se tome los contornos internos y solo me tome el rectangulo principal?

[image: La imagen muestra los contornos tomados por el codigo]

Aqui se ve la imagen que esta tomando para el calculo del area todas las superficies cerradas por los rectangulos, como se puede hacer para que me tome solo el mas grande, sin tomar en cuenta los rectangulos internos o etiquetas?

Algo asi:

[image: Hoja de papel]

El codigo que estoy usando para calclular el area es el siguiente:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread("363110442338.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

canny = cv2.Canny(gray, 10,150)
canny = cv2.dilate(canny, None, iterations=1)
canny = cv2.erode(canny, None, iterations=1)
cnts,_ = cv2.findContours(canny, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

  for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (0,255,0), 2)
    cv2.imshow('Calculo de Area y Reconocimiento de imagen', image);
    print(area)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Este código funciona con las limitantes, pero tambien note que cuando el objeto se acerca a la camara su area cambia, por ejemplo, el objeto puede ser del tamaño de una hoja carta en su ancho y largo, sin embargo cuando tiene diferente altura el area se altera debido a la cercania del lente. En la imagen el recuadro azul representa la camara
[image: error altura]

En la imagen se puede ver que el objeto a la izquierda mide de ancho y largo de una hoja carta, el objeto de la derecha es mas pequeño que el primero, sin embargo, debido a la altura el sistema toma el area como iguales

Como puedo mejorar el codigo?

Comment: Hola Jesus te recomiendo leer [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), la pregunta debe de ser sobre un problema específico (has puesto dos completamente distintos). Además el segundo no aportas ningún ejemplo ni código reproducible, por lo que la pregunta caería en **basada en opiniones**. Aun así he respondido a tu primera pregunta.

Comment: Por orientarte con la segunda, OpenCV no tiene, ni existe, ningún algoritmo simple de cálculo de profundidad ya que con una cámara RGB no puede conseguirse. La única forma de conseguir "estimar" la profundidad es creando una red neuronal de detección de profundidad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes dos problemas que son completamente distintos:

### Elegir el contorno más grande

Simplemente en vez de representar las imagenes, te quedas con el area del contorno `cv.contourArea()` más grade y después lo representas. Para hacer esto tu código queda así:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = cv.imread("caja2.jpg")
image_copy = np.array(image)
gray = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

canny = cv.Canny(gray, 10,150)
canny = cv.dilate(canny, None, iterations=1)
canny = cv.erode(canny, None, iterations=1)
cnts,_ = cv.findContours(canny, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)


#Buscas el contorno más grande
lista_areas = []
for c in cnts:
    area = cv.contourArea(c)
    lista_areas.append(area)


#Te quedas con el area más grande
mas_grande = cnts[lista_areas.index(max(lista_areas))]

#Representas el contorno más grande
area = cv.contourArea(mas_grande)
x,y,w,h = cv.boundingRect(mas_grande)
cv.rectangle(image_copy, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (0,255,0), 2)
cv.imshow('Calculo de Area y Reconocimiento de imagen', image_copy)
cv.waitKey(0)
```

Los cambios han sido:

- Uso el bucle `for` en vez de para pintar la imagen y representarla, para buscar el área más grande
- `cnts[lista_areas.index(max(lista_areas))]`: aquí extraigo el área más grande, después cojo el indice y con ese indice, extraigo el contorno más grande de `cnts`
- Por último pinto la imagen con su contorno adecuado

**Otra opción**

Otra opción es usar `cv.threshold()` con algunos de los umbrales que ofrecen y encontrar el umbral y preprocesado que se adapta a tu imagen

Comment: Me funciona bastante bien, la pregunta que tengo es si hay posibilidad de que se contornee la imagen (es decir, que en vez del rectangulo me contornee la imagen, se puede?)

Comment: Pero esta pregunta no es la que has planteado, ni has intentado, esta pregunta la acabas de hacer ahora y sería una nueva distinta a las anteriores.  como aparece en [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y te he comentado arriba, las preguntas deben ser específicas sobre un tema concreto. Disculpame no es mi intención no ayudar, todo lo contrario, estoy deseando ayudarte, pero es que no te estás ajustando a las normas del sitio...